# Checking the relation between two questions

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, correlation

I have set of answers obtained from different respondents to the following questions (with available answers):

Q1 --> Do you think **this** practice is bad?
A1 --> YES or NO.

Q2 --> What is the severity of **this** practice?
A2 --> 1-5 Likert scale answer.

Q3 --> What is the priority of **this** practice?
A3 --> 1-5 Likert scale answer.

Q1, Q2, and Q3 is repeated for every category and represented with "**this**" in the questions. I have 12 categories. I want to check if the answers of Q1-Q2 and Q2-Q3 are correlated with each other for every category. Does the number of samples matter? Which statistical test can I use for this purpose?

Narrow version Cross link: `https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548624/checking-the-relation-between-two-questions`

Comment: Please do not cross post.

Comment: if you have statistical model, then the number of samples does not matter but if you dont have any statistical model the result that you will find will depend on the total number of samples and ideally as the total number of samples approaches to infinity the result derived from the true statistical model as well as over the samples that are available will be equal.